# Fitting data (and getting normal vectors) to planes that can be vertical

Tags: regression, fitting, curve-fitting, geometry

I have many individual datasets of $(x,y,z)$ coordinates. I'd like to see if the coordinates form a plane (and if they do, I'd then like to compute a unit normal to the plane). My original method was to simply fit to $z=ax+by+c$ via least-squares minimization. However, some of my data is nearly vertical in $z$ such that this breaks down. What is the best way to address this without specifically checking every dataset to see if the data forms a vertical plane?

Here is a toy dataset: `coords = [3.64811 7.61531 9.05108; 3.53604 4.82801 9.05108; 3.53604 4.82801 6.34192; 3.64811 7.61531 6.34192]`

Comment: You ask whether the coordinates are linearly dependent *and* whether they form a plane rather than a point or line.  The answers to the duplicate address all these points.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up going with an orthogonal regression method instead, which actually seems more appropriate with what I'm trying to do. It was easy to implement, and I referred to [this post](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/297854-best-fitting-a-plane-ax-by-cz-0-where-c-could-be-0) for anyone interested.

Comment: That is the method I described in the duplicate thread: it computes the singular values (of a centered matrix) and uses relatively small singular values to detect collinearity.